# running two calls Asynchronously using completable Future

Tags: java, parallel-processing, completable-future

i'm running a rest call once i get the output i want to run two calls asynchronously with the result

one is to persist the data to the data base and another calling another web services with those results

```
CompletableFuture<List<Tweet>> tweetFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> restUtils.getTweetsByUserId(userId))
                .thenApply(TweetConvertor::convertToTweet);

                  tweetFuture.thenApply(tweetRepository::saveAll);
                 return   tweetFuture.thenCompose(this::deleteTweets);
```

here first i called an rest service and convert the result to an List of tweet object and , then i want to run two parallel calls saving the list to DB and send it to another Rest call , my doubt is that

```
            tweetFuture.thenApply(tweetRepository::saveAll);
             return   tweetFuture.thenCompose(this::deleteTweets);
```

weather these two calls are run synchronously

Comment: Please show more respect for your reader. Use proper case, punctuation, complete sentences, etc. This site is meant to more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room.

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the tweets even if the save to database operation fails?